# Set a custom post type's title and slug to match the current date

Tags: slug, title, date

I have seen similar questions asked, but mine is a little different. I want to register a post type called `'minutes'` that doesn't allow you to add a `title` or a `slug`, but when you publish (or autosave) it automatically gives the post a title of today's date, and a `slug` with a canonical representation of the date.

So, title would be `"December 7th, 2012"` and the slug would be `/minutes/12-7-2012`.

I don't want the `title` bar or `slug` to even be present on the editor page, because I don't want people to think they can fill in their own title. However, I think disabling titles entirely when registering a custom post type means it can't even get an auto-generated one. I don't know for sure, though, so maybe you can help me understand it. Thank you.

Comment: All other aspects of the post would be editable though? This is just a way to control the title and slug of a post?

Answer (score 1):

This is completely untested, but the principles are in place. Get today's date and built the title, build the slug and then insert the post as a draft.

This doesn't take care of disabling the title field from being edited. I imagine what you're looking for would be a Javascript solution that just looks for the field and disables it.

**Build the title**

```
function wpse_75303_build_title() {
    $output = date( 'M jS, Y' );
    return $output;
}
```

**Build the slug**

```
function wpse_75303_build_slug() {
    $output = date( 'n-j-Y' );
    return $output;
}
```

**Build the post**

```
function wpse_75303_build_date_post() {
    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'  => wpse_75303_build_title(),
      'post_name'   => wpse_75303_build_slug(),
      'post_status' => 'draft'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
```

**Fire the action**

```
add_action( 'edit_post', 'wpse_75303_build_date_post' );
```